# Idiomatic haskell code

Tags: haskell

Given a list `lst` and a number `n` the following bit of code outputs a list with `n` distinct elements from the given list `lst`.

```
rndsel :: (Eq a, RandomGen g) => [a] -> g -> Int -> [a]
rndsel lst _ 0 = []
rndsel lst g n = schar:(rndsel rem g (n-1))
  where schar = lst !! index
        index = head $ randomRs (0, ll-1) g
        ll = length lst
        rem = delete schar lst
```

I would like to know if there is any way I can improve this code in terms of readability, eloquence and if I can make it more idiomatic haskell code?

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is a more appropriate place for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. For better compositionality with other functions on list it's better to move the input list parameter to last position, i.e.:

   > g -> Int -> **[a]** -> [a]

   This way you'll be able to use your function like this:

   ```
   nub . rndsel g n . sort $ someList
   ```
2. It also feels more natural to change the order of "generator" with the "n" parameters, as the "n" seems to be the most dynamic one:

   > **Int -> g** -> [a] -> [a]
3. The `!!` function is partial and will present you with a runtime error if you provide it an index larger than the size of the list. Lately it's considered a bad practice to use partial functions.
4. The `head` function is partial too.
5. List is not an index-based structure and accessing it's elements by index (the `!!` function) has an `O(n)` complexity, which is very ineffective.
6. The problem domain of your function is easily dividable into two other simpler ones: shuffling and taking a part of the shuffling result. There's a lot of good shuffling algorithms implementations out there, the [**Fisher Yates**](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Random_shuffle#Purely_functional) seems most appropriate in your case. It has the following signature:

   ```
   shuffle :: RandomGen g => g -> [a] -> ([a], g)
   ```

   Now using it we can easily reimplement your function as follows:

   ```
   rndsel :: (Eq a, RandomGen g) => Int -> g -> [a] -> [a]
   rndsel n g = take n . fst . shuffle g
   ```